# Angular bind once vs. track by performance

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a ng-repeat directive with some filters on it and massive DOM inside each repetition. For example:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat='task in tasks'>
        <!--Some DOM with many bindings-->
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to improve performance a bit, but I want to keep two-way binding.
One way to do it is to insert track by:

```
ng-repeat='task in tasks track by task.id'
```

The other way is to use native bind once in bindings:

```
{{::task.name}}
```

Obviously I cannot use both of them because in this case two way binding will not work. 
How can I measure DOM rebuild speed? Which way is more effective?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**These are not mutually exclusive constructs and both have different uses.**

Using `track by` simply **allows Angular to better manage the DOM when items are added or removed**. By default, it uses a hash of the entire object, which can be slow and inefficient compared to a simple atomic value.

Using one time binding syntax however simply reduces the number of total watches in the application. **This makes the app more responsive when performing updates because it has less things to watch.**

Comment: Yes, I understand how it works and what's the difference between them, but the main question is - how can I test performance of each construction?

Comment: My point though is that you cannot test them relative to one another because they affect different things. There is no reason not to use `track by` if you have an atomic and unique key because it will most certainly result in faster DOM processing in the `ng-repeat`. You should also use one-time binding on your individual items unless you absolutely need to have them be dynamically updatable.

Comment: They might affect different things, but they definitely can conflict with each other. An app I'm building loads a table full of data. Once the data is loaded, it will not change, so I can one-time bind everything when the data loads. However, I have a refresh button, when pushed, goes and refetches the data. Any changes I want to display, but this is also a list of 300-400 items, so using `track by` speeds it up a lot. However, using both causes any changes to not get updated. How can I use both of these and still show any updates on reload?

Comment: @jkjustjoshing i have the exact same problem and was wondering which was was more performant as well... my hunch is that bind once is still better because $watch gets evaluated on digest no matter what where as track by is only valuable if you're updating the array.

Answer (score 0):

Great question.

The answer: it depends, but mostly one time bindings are a better option unless your app is very small.

Why?
Because if your app is middle sized or large you will have watch count problem. If you blow number of watches to more then 2000 your app will feel sluggish on less powerful devices whatever you do. Watches will slow your application all the time. On every digest cycle. So your primary concern regarding performance should be to keep that watch count down. And removing watches from stuff inside ng-repeat helps the most obviously.

On the other hand track by will speed up refresh of a table a little but it's a optimization that you should take only if you know your app will stay small (bellow 2000 watches)